# How use logic operators in jsrender

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I have

```
{{if name && secondName}}
{{=name}}/{{=secondName}}
{{/if}}
```

but this not worked.
I catch error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&

That I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an out-of-date version of JsRender. The syntax is `{{:name}}`, and `&&` should work fine in current versions.